# Zend Framework 2 - Doctrine 2 - How to use GeoPointFields

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db, geopoints

I need to implement a `GeoPointField` with Doctrine2.

It seems that Zend and Doctrine don't support it natively...

Is there a best practice for validating such an input? In the database I'd use a simple string field, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),?\s*(\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/
```

This regexp validates and captures GEO input:

- Latitude, Longitude
- Latitude Longitude
- Coords copied directly from GoogleMaps

Comment: I chose a standard regex validation, this works just fine except for the error message: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14068446/1331671

Comment: @Ron, so you was simply asking about form field and validation of user input?

Comment: no, at first i wanted to have a built-in solution. but it seems that going with regex is a lighter and easier way. thanks for your post anyway :)

Comment: @Ron, sorry for my inattentiveness. I revised my answer. I wrote this `regexp` for validating GEO coordinates input in one of my projects. Works perfectly.