# Zend Framework 2 - Annotation form, RegEx validation and custom error messages

Tags: php, regex, zend-form, zend-framework2

As outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14067212/1331671) I'm working with `GeoPositionFields`. Because this is not supported from Zend, I went with a standard `RegEx` validator.

It works great but I still need a custom error message - any ideas how to achieve this?

The one in my example just does nothing...

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Form\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
 * @Form\Validator({"name":"Regex", "options":{"pattern":"/(-?\d{1,3}\D\d+)[^\d-]+(-?\d{1,3}\D\d+)/"}})
 * @Form\ErrorMessage("My custom message")
 * @Form\Attributes({"type":"text"})
 * @Form\Options({"label":"GeoPos"})
 *
 */
protected $geopoint;
```

Even this one is just beeing ignored:

```
@Form\Messages({"regexNotMatch": "My custom message"})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to overwrite the default messages using the `messages` key from the options.

Try this (i guess you'll have to trim this into one line though for the annotations to work ;) That's up to you, hehe.

```
@Form\Validator({
    "name":"regex", 
    "options":{
        "pattern":"/(-?\d{1,3}\D\d+)[^\d-]+(-?\d{1,3}\D\d+)/",
        "messages":{
            "regexInvalid":"Regex is invalid, Booo!",
            "regexNotMatch": "Input doesn't match, bleeeeh!",
            "regexErrorous": "Internal error, i'm like wtf!"
        }
    }
})
```

Each Validator has it's own messages. You're best advised to see the Source-Code to find out what ErrorMessages are present within each Element. To give you an example, please follow [this link (click)](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Validator/Regex.php#L23-L25) to see how to find out about the messages-keys.

When using the array-style-syntax for creating forms outside of Annotations, it may be a little bit safer to go the statis approach for the keys like

```
'messages' => array(
    \Zend\Validator\Regex::INVALID => "Regex is invalid, Booo!",
    //etc...
)
```

Since strings - at least in theory - could always change, the constants won't.

Comment: hm... still no reaction: `@Form\Validator({"name":"Regex", "options":{"pattern":"/(-?\d{1,3}\D\d+)[^\d-]+(-?\d{1,3}\D\d+)/"}, "messagesTemplates":{"regexInvalid":"Regex is invalid, Booo!","regexNotMatch": "Input doesn't match, bleeeeh!","regexErrorous": "Internal error, i'm like wtf!"}})`

Comment: Are you getting default error messages if you leave the templates? Any errors at all?

Comment: My bad, it's `messages` not `messagesTemplates` - editted the answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),?\s*(\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/
```

This regexp validates and captures GEO input:

- In format *Latitude, Longitude*
- In format *Latitude Longitude*
- Coordinates copied directly from GoogleMaps

Comment: thanks for the answer but the expression is not the question here ;)

Comment: @Ron, let it be nice addition to this question also. Kinda New Year present :)